# JQuery .Off not unbinding my .On click event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to unbind `click` with no success.

the idea is that when calling `doUnbind()` method it should unbind the `click` event however it always brings me into 'On` event

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').on('click', 'button.update', function() {
         alert('clicked');
    });
}

function doUnbind() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').off('click', 'button.update', function () {
        // should unbind but not working 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `$('#activeListing tbody').off('click', 'button.update');` or to unbind only specific event, use namespace or referenced handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to remove a function which isn't added. You need to use a named function so you can tell jQuery which function to remove.

```
function addClick() {
    alert('clicked');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').on('click', 'button.update', addClick);
}

function doUnbind() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').off('click', 'button.update', addClick); 
}
```

You can also remove all event listeners at once, but be sure you actually want to do that:

```
function doUnbindAll() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').off('click', 'button.update'); 
}
```

Comment: If you want to unbind all the click handlers alternatively you can do $('#activeListing tbody').off('click', 'button.update'); without needing to name the function. But being specific is always better so the solution depicted in this answer is better.

Comment: Thanks @cmertayak, I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using event namespace:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').on('click.update', 'button.update', function() {
         alert('clicked');
    });
}

function doUnbind() {
    $('#activeListing tbody').off('click.update');
}
```